SwiftUI Only hide dot indicator on the last screen of Tabview
I'm working on a project written in SwiftUI and I want to create an Onboarding screen which has 4 pages. Each page has a full-screen image introducing about app. I use Tabview and enable page indicators. I can see the dot indicator at bottom, but requirement is when user slide on the last page, the dot should be hidden.
Here is my code
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                Image("onboard_1")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Image("onboard_2")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Image("onboard_3")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Image("onboard_4")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .padding(.top, 0)
            .background(.black)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }

I read on Apple document, it said the dot will be hidden automatically when using no more page left but it seems not working as expected
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))

Here is Apple document
public struct PageTabViewStyle : TabViewStyle {

    /// A style for displaying the page index view
    public struct IndexDisplayMode : Sendable {

        /// Displays an index view when there are more than one page
        public static let automatic: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode

        /// Always display an index view regardless of page count
        @available(watchOS 8.0, *)
        public static let always: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode

        /// Never display an index view
        @available(watchOS 8.0, *)
        public static let never: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode
    }

    /// Creates a new `PageTabViewStyle` with an index display mode
    public init(indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode = .automatic)
}


Try this approach using TabView(selection: ...) with .tag() and
hiding the desired last page dots, such as in this example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentTab = 0  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {  // <--- here
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tag(0) // <--- here
                
                Image(systemName: "info")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tag(1) // <--- here
                
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tag(2) // <--- here
                
                Image(systemName: "tray")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .tag(3) // <--- here
                
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: currentTab == 3 ? .never : .always)) // <--- here
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .padding(.top, 0)
            //  .background(.black)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
    
}


thank you, but I tried, on the last page, the last dot is inactive, it stopped at the third dot, but they still show

I tested my answer on iOS 18.2, using Xcode 16.2 and on MacCatalyst macOS 15.2, and the dots
are not displayed when you navigate to the last page, as per your
...requirement is when user slide on the last page, the dot should be hidden. Note I don't understand your comment.

yes, that is requirement. I mean when I tried, the dots still not disappear on page 4. and when I tried on page 4, the THIRD dot is Active, the FORTH dot is unactive. it's weird

It does not happen with my code, maybe you have other code that affects the display. Try just my code and tell me what you get.

oh no, you're right, I wrapped the Image.tag(3) on a NavigationLink to navigate to another View. I remove the NavigationLink and it works now. I will find other ways to implement Navigation Link. Thank you
